# T-SQL - How to use results of a query to select multiple rows based on a count

Tags: sql, sql-server

Considering the below example `Person` table, I am looking for a way to return multiple rows based on an X value. So, if the `BagsOut` count is, say 3, I would want 3 copies of the row returned or if it was 2 then 2 copies should be returned, and so on:

```
ID      Name      BagsOut
1       Ken       1
2       Dave      3
3       Ben       2
```

Desired result:

```
ID      Name      BagsOut
1       Ken       1
2       Dave      3
2       Dave      3
2       Dave      3
3       Ben       2
3       Ben       2
```

Is it possible to write this into a single query? I am using T-SQL.

Many thanks in advance for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use recursive CTE to achieve this.

```sql
declare @t table(ID int,      Name char(5),      BagsOut int)

insert into @t values
(1       ,'Ken',       1)
,(2       ,'Dave',     3)
,(3       ,'Ben',       2)

;with cte_bags as
(
select id, name, BagsOut,1 as currentRow from @t 
union all
select id, name, BagsOut, currentRow+1 
from cte_bags
where currentRow < BagsOut)
select id, name, BagsOut from cte_bags
order by id
```

| id | name | BagsOut |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ken | 1 |
| 2 | Dave | 3 |
| 2 | Dave | 3 |
| 2 | Dave | 3 |
| 3 | Ben | 2 |
| 3 | Ben | 2 |

Comment: @DavyC, welcome. If it answers your question, please mark it as answer. It will be helpful for future visitors of the site.